# Authenticate users when login

Tags: forms, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm a beginner and I'm doing a Rails Tuturial https://www.learnenough.com/ruby-on-rails-6th-edition-tutorial/basic_login#sec-finding_and_authenticating_a_user>

Last lesson i `create` a new `user` and I'm verifying in the ``` rails``console ``` using `booleans` to prove if users `email` and `password` match to `login` session.

This is my code in the `session` `controller` file:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
     user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

And to verify in the rails console:

> > user = User.first
> >     => User id: 1, name: "Rails Tutorial", email: "example@railstutorial.org", created_at: "2020-02-13 01:04:12", updated_at: "2020-02-13 01:04:12", password_digest: [FILTERED]
> >
> > !!(user && user.authenticate('railst1234'))
> >     => false

The question here is why returns FALSE if the email and password info. suppose to be right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because you are trying to authenticate an encrypted password but creating without given password_confirmation to user model. Here is a good [link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) for understanding passwords on user.

[This](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/InstanceMethodsOnActivation/authenticate) could also help you if you don't want encrypted passwords for user.